# Newbie issue with python, script works fine on other os

Tags: python, linux, bots

I am using a bot with python to create accounts on a website. When I use it on my windows machine with python installed, it works fine. I bought a linux VPS yesterday (Ubuntu 16.04) and my script apparently isn't working anymore. This is the error I get on my linux machine:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "roblox.py", line 2, in <module>
    from utils import *
  File "/home/py/newbot/utils.py", line 18
    key, *values = line.split(" ")
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The line in the script its referring to is this

```
def string_to_dict(headers):
headers_dict = {}
for line in headers.split("\n"):
    if not line: continue
    line = line.strip()
    key, *values = line.split(" ")
    key = key[:-1]
    if not (key and values): continue
    headers_dict[key] = " ".join(values)
return headers_dict
```

Any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Comment: You are on a version of Python that doesn't support that syntax. If you are on Ubuntu 16, try invoking `python3`

Comment: Likely running python2 rather than 3; specify version as you execute(/usr/bin/python3 /home/py/robox.py) or update #! @ top. (#!/usr/bin/python3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, you need to run this in Python3. The shortest answer is:

1. Install python3, which may not already be on your machine: `$ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install python3`
2. Get in the habit of using a shebang in your script files. Add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the first line of your script to direct the shell to invoke python3 instead of python2 -- most systems come with /usr/bin/python aliased to python2 installations.

You can find out more about sourcing files in the Bash shell (default shell for Ubuntu 16.04) [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html).

The longer answer -- if you're wondering why the code doesn't work in Python2 but does work in Python3 -- is that Python3 introduced extended iterable unpacking in [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), but this feature was not implemented in Python2.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is invalid in python 2. Run your script with `python3`.

Comment: Welp, thanks a bunch! Works fine now, you saved my day.